# Springboot Application Performance affected after adding Jasypt encryption dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, jasypt

My Springboot app (2.3.0) was working smooth until this Jasypt dependency was introduced:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And then the only change was replacing the plain text password in my application.properties to ENC(***):

```
datasource.password=ENC(*************************************)
```

How can I improve the performance? The application pages that used to load within milliseconds are now taking 4-5 seconds to load.

Comment: we might need full code to understand the problem. How are you decrypting the password in your code and also where/how do you use that property?

Comment: There is no code change. Property is used using @value annotation.

Comment: is your bean singleton or prototype? How is your bean injected/used in other classes?

Comment: by default, prototype

Comment: Probably that could be the reason, spring boot is trying to decrypt for every instance. Encryption and decryption operations are usually slow. May be you should abstract that property to a separate bean and mark it as singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took jasypt source code and replaced a line to simply return false.

This was the line in jasypt source code that was causing the slowness :
RefreshScopeRefreshedEventListener.java

```
boolean isAssignable(String className, Object value) {
    try {
        return ClassUtils.isAssignableValue(ClassUtils.forName(className, null),value);
     }...
```